# vague concept about appcompatv7 in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

appcompat(v7) library gets add up automatically when you are using a minimum API level for your application development. Why am I getting appcompat with API 11? I mean if its already included in API level 11 why does it add up then. Can and should I remove it?

Comment: You should actually start setting minSDK to 14, for your own better future. Devices lower than SDK 11 are already less than 20% in distribution.

Comment: Thank you I actually had posted a question related to your opinion in the past. They replied if you wanna get expertise in android you should cover every aspect of Android. BTW thanks

Comment: Your question has bothered every Android developer I believed. I started my project by supporting minSDK 8, but soon it has become more and more cumbersome, as the audience is just becoming irrelevant. I guess the answer to your other question is not "should I support <11?", but "when should I stop supporting <11?"